# Best practice for Android app: Multiple services or just one

Tags: android, service

I'm working on an Android app which controls some BLE enabled hardware. It also accesses a Server API and use location services.
The current app organises this as three different services: Location (system service), BLE service and Server service.
That means a lot of broadcasts coming to the GUI part of the app and a lot of logic in the Activity.
I would like to move more functionality into a background service for two reasons:
 - Enable the background service to perform interactions with both BLE, server and receive locations while being in the background.
 - Simplify the interface between the Activity and the services (also makes it easier to test functionality).

I would like some "best practice" inputs on what solution would be best:

1: Create an additional service which is the entry point for the Activity and which then starts and communicates with BLE, Server and location services.

2: Merge my server and BLE code into a single service and add locations to that?

I'm kind of leaning towards 2 to avoid too many broadcast being thrown around making things more complex even with the more functionality getting stuffed into one service.

Any thoughts? Any comments on several services communicating?

Thanks

Comment: take a look into that library to simplify the broadcasts code http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: Hi, thanks
The Otto bus code seems like a nice way to handle system messaging, but broadcasts are walking ok too. It doesn't really answer things like whether multiple services talking together is a bad idea?

Comment: That's why I made a comment and not a proper answer. I know broadcasts works fine, I've used to use them. But it's simply a much cleaner code to use otto. The rest of your question I believe it's more a matter of structure and open to debate/discussions/opinions, and there won't be a definitive answer